# Create a new variable based on any 2 conditions being true

Tags: r, variables, binary-data

I have a dataframe in R with 4 variables and would like to create a new variable based on any 2 conditions being true on those variables.
I have attempted to create it via if/else statements however would require a permutation of every variable condition being true. I would also need to scale to where I can create a new variable based on any 3 conditions being true. I am not sure if there is a more efficient method than using if/else statements?

My example:
I have a dataframe X with following column variables

```
x1 = c(1,0,1,0)
X2 = c(0,0,0,0)
X3 = c(1,1,0,0)
X4 = c(0,0,1,0)
```

I would like to create a new variable X5 if any 2 of the variables are true (eg ==1)
The new variable based on the above dataframe would produce X5 (1,0,1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done by using the `apply` function:

```
x1 = c(1,0,1,0)
x2 = c(0,0,0,0)
x3 = c(1,1,0,0)
x4 = c(0,0,1,0)

df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)

df$x5 <- apply(df,1,function(row) ifelse(sum(row != 0) == 2, 1, 0))

  x1 x2 x3 x4 X5
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  1  1
4  0  0  0  0  0
```

`apply` with option 1 means: Do this function on every row. To scale this up to 3...N true values, just change the number in the `ifelse` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(x1,X2,X3,X4)
#Code
df$X5 <- ifelse(rowSums(df,na.rm=T)==2,1,0)

  x1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  1  1
4  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: You could simplify this to `+(rowSums(df) == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df$X5 <- 1*(apply(df == 1, 1, sum)  == 2)
```

or

```
df$X5 <- 1*(mapply(sum, df) == 2)
```

**Output**

```
> df
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  1  0  1
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
0  0  0  0  0
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4)
```